# Resize, relocate and make an initially invisible edit control visible

Tags: winapi, mfc

I am writing an MFC dialog application with a static control and an edit control (which is initially set to be invisible) on it. The static has regions (for example, A01, A02, A03, A04, B01, B02, ...) at runtime like this:
[image]

When I double-click mouse inside some particular rectangle of the static (A02, for example), I want the edit control resize to the size of the rectangle and cover that rectangle (A02, for example) like this:
[image]

However, this is not until I input something (for example, the character 'a') and delete them. That is, when I double-click A02, the caret of the edit control appears but I still can see the "A02" caption of the rectangle:
[image]

Below is how I make the edit control visible and change its position (`rtEdit` is the `CRect` object corresponding to A02 in this case, and `m_rtPanelParent` is the `CRect` object corresponding to the whole static. I get `m_rtPanelParent` by `m_stcPanel.GetWindowRect (&m_rtPanelParent);` and `ScreenToClient (&m_rtPanelParent);` in my dialog's `OnInitDialog()`):

```
void CStaticPanel::OnLButtonDblClk(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    .....
    .....
    m_pDlgParent->m_editCaption.SetWindowPos (&wndTop, m_pDlgParent->m_rtPanelParent.left + rtEdit.left, m_pDlgParent->m_rtPanelParent.top + rtEdit.top, rtEdit.Width (), rtEdit.Height (), SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
    m_pDlgParent->m_editCaption.SetFocus ();

    CStatic::OnLButtonDblClk(nFlags, point);
}
```

I think the edit control has correct size and position of the rectangle (which I double-clicked in). See below:

[image]

I would appreciate any help with this situation.

Comment: Hide the static panel with `ShowWindow(SW_HIDE)`. Show it again when the focus changes to another panel.

Comment: Dear @AndrewTruckle: I just want the edit control covers some region of the static (for example, A02), so I do not want to hide the whole static.

Comment: Dear @HansPassant: I set the tab order of the edit to be 26 and the tab order of the whole static to be 27. Could you elaborate on your points for me? Thank you.

Comment: It still needs more detail. Show the paint function where you draw A01, A02,... It needs enough code so we can duplicate this problem.

Comment: But logic tells you if the edit is 26 and the static 27 that the edit is drawn before the static. That is the wrong way round.

Comment: Make sure the parent window has the `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` style set.

Comment: Since the regions are displayed in a static control, you'll want WS_CLIPSIBLINGS on the edit control.  And you will likely need to make sure the edit control's Z-order is on top.

Answer (score 1):

The edit control appears to have smaller height. Make sure the edit control completely covers the static control. For debugging you can create edit control with borders so it's more clear where it appears.

```
void CStaticPanel::OnLButtonDblClk(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    CStatic::OnLButtonDblClk(nFlags, point);

    CRect rc;
    GetWindowRect(&rc);
    m_pDlgParent->ScreenToClient(&rc);
    m_pDlgParent->m_editCaption.SetWindowPos(&wndTop, 
        rc.left, rc.top, rc.Width(), rc.Height(), SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
    m_pDlgParent->m_editCaption.SetFocus();
}
```

Comment: Dear @Barmak Shemirani: I do not want the edit control covers the whole static control. I just want it covers some region of the static (for example, A02).

Comment: Add more details to your question, and show what it looks like when edit control has borders

Comment: Dear @Barmak Shemirani: I have added some information to my question. Thank you.